# Как найти все структуры запроса SELECT?

Tags: sql, postgresql

В курсовой работе по базам данных необходимо найти 15 различных структур SELECT запроса.
В bnf нотации:

> Оператор выборки ::= Табличное выражение [**ORDER BY** {{Имя
> столбца-результата [**ASC** | **DESC**]} | {Положительное целое [**ASC** |
> **DESC**]}}.,..];
>
> Табличное выражение ::=
>
> Select-выражение
>
> [
>
> {**UNION** | **INTERSECT** | **EXCEPT**} [ALL]
>
> {Select-выражение | TABLE Имя таблицы | Конструктор значений таблицы}
> ]
>
> Select-выражение ::=
>
> **SELECT** [**ALL** | **DISTINCT**]
>
> {{{Скалярное выражение | Функция агрегирования | Select-выражение} [AS
> Имя столбца]}.,..}
>
> | {{Имя таблицы|Имя корреляции}.*}
>
> | *
>
> **FROM** {
>
> {Имя таблицы [**AS**] [Имя корреляции] [(Имя столбца.,..)]}
>
> | {Select-выражение [**AS**] Имя корреляции [(Имя столбца.,..)]}
>
> | Соединенная таблица }.,..
>
> [**WHERE** Условное выражение]
>
> [**GROUP BY** {[{Имя таблицы|Имя корреляции}.]Имя столбца}.,..]
>
> [**HAVING** Условное выражение]

оператора SELECT точно есть 13 из них, но в упор не вижу последние три...
Вот какие уже нашел:

1. Самый простой SELECT + FROM + WHERE
2. Подзапрос во FROM
3. Подзапрос в SELECT
4. Подзапрос в WHERE
5. Использование ORDER BY
6. UNION|INTERSECT
7. GROUP BY
8. GROUP BY + Подзапрос в HAVING (При этом GROUP BY + HAVING является просто усложнением структуры, потому не подходит)
9. Корелляционный запрос
10. Использование псевдонимов (ALIAS)

Так как базу данных в курсовой я создаю в PostgreSQL, возможности этой СУБД тоже можно использовать, но пока что вижу возможность только с FETCH сработать каким-либо образом.

Comment: Если понимаете, то зачем всё таки публикуте вопрос?

Comment: В надежде, что всё-таки подскажут, какие структуры я упустил...

Answer (score 2):

Возьмите [синтаксис `SELECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) и выписывайте из него элементы для своего списка.

Я просто не понимаю, по какому принципу вы составили свой список. Почему псевдонимы одним элементом списка отдельно от всего, а подзапросы упоминаете 5 раз (табличный подзапрос обязывает использовать алиас, например), почему having у вас привязан group by и требует почему-то подзапрос

```
select 1 having false;
```

Синтаксически полностью корректный запрос, возвращающий всегда 0 строк.

> Самый простой SELECT + FROM + WHERE

Самый простой select выглядит вот так:

```
select;
```

Всё, это весь запрос и это не шутка. Разрешён начиная с PostgreSQL 9.4, возвращает ровно одну строку без каких-либо данных.

```
select some_function();
```

Используется повсеместно при использовании хранимых функций.

```
select 1 where some_condition();
```

Тоже допустимых запрос.

```
select * from tablename;
```

Конечно тоже нормальный запрос. Поэтому я не понимаю, почему вы эти разные выражения посчитали как одно и как вообще составляли список.